# ->Running wc command using execv

Tags: c, unix, execv

I am trying to create a simple function that counts lines from a text file and print it by using Unix command `wc` (word count). I don't understand why it does not work; I tried different paths for `wc` location but nothing works.

Instead, I get this error:

```
�%r  : No such file or directory
```

I want to use the `wc` command.

Code:

```
void count_lines() {
    int p;
    p=fork();
    if(p == 0) {
        char* args[] = {"./wc","1.txt",NULL};
        execv("./wc",args);
        perror(execv);
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("waiting for child\n");
    wait(NULL);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: no such file or directory error.

Comment: @Guy That's exactly the problem: there's no `wc` found in the path you have (i.e., current directory).

Comment: Also note the reason you have some "junk" printed in front of the message is because you're passing address of `execv` to `perror` instead of a *string*.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include` - and how does `perror(execv)` even compile in modern C?. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @P.P. Any decent compiler should complain if you attempt to pass a function pointer where a `char*` is required - I suspect Guy has forgotten to enable a sensible set of warnings.

Comment: Note also that after a failed `execv()` call in a child process after calling `fork()` it's better to call `_exit()` instead of `exit()`.  `exit()` will do things like flush output buffers, which get copied from the parent process.  That can corrupt data files being written.  `exit()` is also not async-signal-safe, and making non-async-signal-safe function calls can be problematic in the child of a multithreaded process after calling `fork()` and before a successful call to an `execv()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct below two lines in your code. Always provide full path to the file location. In case of unsuccessful command execution, you need to check access permission to the file location including permission to execute the file or command:-

```
char* args[]={"wc","-l","/full/path/1.txt",NULL};
execv("/usr/bin/wc",args);
```

Normally all unix/Linux commands should be in directory location `/usr/bin/`. To get the full path for a command just try like below:-

```
which command #here command can be wc, ls etc. so try which wc
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for you advice, only very few people advice us. Will follow your instructor in future. :-)

Comment: @TobySpeight, modified little bit based on your advice. Thanks

Comment: there is any way to avoid using the full path for 1.txt? i tried to move it to the directory where im running the code but it does not work. if im using full path i cannot run the code on different computer.

Comment: try like `./1.txt`  or  do pwd and get the full path

Comment: just put the full path to wc just follow my example. type `which wc ` you will get the path. I thing problem is with your file. give permission like chmod 666 1.txt

Comment: what is we need to print this result to a file??  implementing wc 1.txt > newfile.txt

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have an binary in your current directory, `./wc` is not going to work. Since you want to use the `wc` command, use the path to it:

```
int p;
p=fork();

if(p == 0) {
    char* args[] = {"wc","1.txt",NULL};
    execv("/usr/bin/wc",args);
    perror("execv");
    exit(0);
}
```

Or you could use [`execvp`](http://%20%20%20%20int%20p;%20%20%20%20%20p=fork();%20%20%20%20%20%20if(p==0)%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20char*%20args[]=%7B%22wc%22,%221.txt%22,NULL%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20execv(%22/usr/bin/wc%22,args);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20perror(%22execv%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20exit(0);%20%20%20%20%20%7D) to let it search `wc` in `PATH`:

```
int p;
p=fork();

if(p == 0) {
    char* args[] = {"wc","1.txt",NULL};
    execvp("wc",args);
    perror("execvp");
    exit(0);
}
```